# How to limit user input to integers greater than 0 using methods?

Tags: ruby, loops, methods

Every time I run this code, I get the prompt "INTEGER GREATER THAN 0", even if I type in an integer greater than 0 for the first try. What I'm trying to accomplish with the verify method is that the input will only accept an integer greater than 0, and if they put in something else it will prompt them "INTEGER GREATER THAN 0". Any help would be appreciated.

```
def verify(input)
  puts "please input an integer > 0"
  input = gets.chomp
  while input == 0 || input.class != Fixnum
    puts "INTEGER GREATER THAN 0"
    input = gets.chomp!.to_i
  end
end

puts "for your first number:"
num_1 = verify(num_1)
puts "for your second number:"
num_2 = verify(num_2)

def div(num_1, num_2)
  num_1 / num_2
end
def rem(num_1,num_2)
  num_1 % num_2
end

puts "#{num_1.to_s} divided by #{num_2.to_s} is #{div(num_1, num_2)} remainder #{rem(num_1,num_2)}"
```

Comment: `gets` returns a string. Cast it to a number. `input = gets.to_i`

Comment: Division, positivity and remainder methods already exist. Also note that `a % b` ≠ `a.remainder b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed two errors.

1.Sergio Tulentsev pointed out that you have to convert input to integer.

2.You will need to return input for verify method.

3.Added is_integer? method.

```
def is_integer?(param)
  true if Integer(param) rescue false
end

def verify(input)
  puts "please input an integer > 0"
  input = gets.chomp

  while input.to_i <= 0 || !is_integer?(input)
    puts "INTEGER GREATER THAN 0"
    input = gets.chomp!
  end

  return input.to_i
end

puts "for your first number:"
num_1 = verify(num_1)
puts "for your second number:"
num_2 = verify(num_2)

def div(num_1, num_2)
  num_1 / num_2
end
def rem(num_1,num_2)
  num_1 % num_2
end

puts "#{num_1.to_s} divided by #{num_2.to_s} is #{div(num_1, num_2)} remainder #{rem(num_1,num_2)}"
```

Comment: when I change the code to use `input = gets.chomp.to_i` rather than not accepting a float, the program simply truncates the float to an integer. what if I want to program to bounce back with the `INTEGER GREATER THAN 0` message?